# Angular Material Slider is not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I cannot make the Angular Material Slider rendering correctly. My code is as follow:

```
    <div class="row formField" ng-cloak>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div>送貨日期</div>
        <div>Delivery Date</div>
    </div>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</div>
<div class="row formField" ng-cloak>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div>進食時間</div>
        <div>Serving Time</div>
    </div>
 <md-content class="md-padding overflow-hidden">
<md-slider-container>
  <span>R</span>
  <md-slider flex="" min="0" max="255" ng-model="color.red" aria-label="red" id="red-slider">
  </md-slider>
  <md-input-container>
    <input flex="" type="number" ng-model="color.red" aria-label="red" aria-controls="red-slider">
  </md-input-container>
</md-slider-container>
</md-content>
</div>
```

But the result is like the following, which is far from good.

[image]

The weird thing is the datepicker is working perfectly, while the slider is not. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the slider can't see angular-material.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/angular-material.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular Material 2, I have directly included theme CDN link:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
```